# I cannot get my extension method to work (C#)

Tags: c#, extension-methods

Any ideas? I marked it as static but it's not working!

```
class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static int Add(this int number, int increment)
    {
        return number + increment;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Do you have the `using ExtensionMethods` statement where you want to use this code?

Comment: You should check your compiler warnings for CS1106.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are missing a static on the class. The compiler should have told you this?

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
```

Comment: this is the solution, but the compiler wont tell you this. as far as it is concerned, the syntax is valid. it has no idea that you are trying to make an extension method.

Answer (score 11):

I think, it needs to be defined in a static class:

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public static class ExtensionMethods
    {
        public static int Add(this int number, int increment)
        {
            return number + increment;
        } 
    }
}
```

You must also include a `using MyNameSpace;` in the code file you want to use them in, unless it is in the same namespace

Comment: Spot on. Extension methods can only be defined on static classes.